# Load more button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a button that loads more posts with AJAX each time you click it. When I click the button the first time, it'll load 3 new posts, but if I click on it a 2nd or 3rd time it will show the same 3 posts. What am I doing wrong?

```
//js file

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#load-more').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '?page_id=90',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            posts_per_page: 3
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $this.text('Loading...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#post-container').append(data);
                $this.text('Load more');
            } else {
                $this.text('No more');
            }
        },
        fail: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
  });
});

//php file
<?php
/*
Template Name: AJAX
*/
?>

<?php
$not_in = array();

$pages = get_posts(array(
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

foreach($pages as $p){
    array_push($not_in, $p->ID);
    //echo $p->ID.' ';
}

query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $_POST['posts_per_page'],
    'post__not_in' =>  $not_in
));

if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
?>
    <div class="blog-post-container cf">
        <div class="blog-img">
        <?=the_post_thumbnail()?>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-post">
            <h2> <?=the_title()?></h2>
            <p>
                <?=the_content()?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
} 
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: You will need to offset the next request by 3 posts.

Comment: @Roberthue, mind making an actual answer out of your comment?